# 2012 Election java program

Tags: java, arrays

> Write a program that uses the file ElectoralVotes.csv and the file ElectionData2012.cvs to calculate the number of electoral votes earned by Obama and Romney in the 2012 election. Your program should build arrays with the state names and the associated electoral votes for that state. The output should show two numbers – the total electoral votes earned by each candidate (Obama and Romney). You should also print each state’s name, the winner, and number of electoral votes won.

What should the for loop consist of ?

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Election2012 {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
    //declarations

         String [] statesEV = new String[52];
         String [] states = new String[52];
         String []  EV = new String [52];
         String [] tokens = new String[5];

    System.out.print("What is the EV file name? ");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String evFileName = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print("What is the vote data file name? ");
    String dataFileName = keyboard.nextLine();

    // Scanner for the electoral votes.
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(evFileName);
    Scanner evScanner = new Scanner(fileReader);

    // Scanner for the election data.
    fileReader = new FileReader(dataFileName);
    Scanner dataScanner = new Scanner(fileReader);



    // we don't need the header.
    evScanner.nextLine(); // burn it.

    // while the file is not empty.
            int i = 0;
    while (evScanner.hasNext())
            {
        statesEV[i]=evScanner.nextLine();
                    tokens = statesEV[i].split(",");
                    states[i]=tokens[0];
                    EV[i]=tokens[1];
                    i++;

            }

    // print to be sure.
    for (i=0 ; i< states.length;i++ )
            {




            }
    // TODO: Go through and process the dataScanner to find the winner.

    // close all Scanners.
    keyboard.close();
    evScanner.close();
    dataScanner.close();
}
```

}

Comment: "[...]  the for loop section is giving me an error on netbeans ." Which error exactly?

Comment: State aState = new State(stateNameFromFile, Integer.parseInt(votesFromFile));
   states[filledInStates++] = aState;  here it says cannot find symbol

Comment: State state = states[i]; here the same thing cannot find symbol class State

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) and add the additional information instead of writing it as a comment.

Comment: You need to import the `State` class.

Comment: thank you I edited the question

Comment: @Gendarme State is not a class its the data being read from the file I have to input the data into an array

Comment: Well, you are treating it like a class. Stop doing that.

Comment: @layla, why don't you simply create the `State` class with two attributes: `stateName` and `votes`? You're on the right path...

Comment: @Gendarme I changed my program got rid of the errors thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @aribeiro Thank you I changed the program would you happen to know what I should put in my for loop  for the array

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing, but if you just want to print the elements in the array, write something like this: `for(int i=0; i < states.length; i++) { System.out.println(states[i]); }` or use the for-each loop like this: `for(String s : states) { System.out.println(s); }`.